# Help with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I written some php code which generates the URL's of pages like `article.php?id=1` etc.
Obviously id is the id of the article taken from database. In the same database table, I have `id`, `title`, and `category` columns.
such as:

```
id      title                   category
1       hello world             general
```

My question is that how can I rewrite the URL's using the title and category of the article instead of id. For example, I want to re-write URL

```
example.com/article.php?id=1
```

To:

```
example.com/general/hello-world
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean that you wanted to rewrite the other way?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that would be to have a php file named general.php and use the [$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're going to use an incoming rewrite rule.

One way would be to extract the category and title from the URL and use another PHP file to find the article

```
RewriteRule .*?\.php - [PT]
RewriteRule  (.*?)/(.*)  articleByCategoryAndTitle.php?category=$1&title=$2
```

A second approach might be to use all three parts like in

```
example.com/category/title-42
```

and then use a RewriteRule to open the article page by ID

```
RewriteRule (?:.*)-(\d+)$ article.php?id=$1
```